# Need help retrieving dynamic values from checkboxes and turning the values into a list. ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a partial view where a supervisor would click and a modal would popup with all of the individuals that they can assign a task to. Each individual has a checkbox in front of their information. I have assigned the checkboxes a value based on the employees id number. I need to get the values of the checkboxes that are selected and pass them into a controller as a list.

My thought process on it is to compare the list of employees the user can assign which I have already created to the selected list. Finally if that user is selected it will be compare to another list to ensure they are not already assigned to the project and then a method runs to assign the individual. Currently without getting the selected values it's adding all of the individuals to the task.

This is my Model

```
 public IEnumerable<EmployeeCurrentUserCanAssign> EmployeesCurrentUserCanAssign { get; set; }
    }
    public class EmployeeCurrentUserCanAssign
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my View

```
<div class="modal" id="groupAssignSettingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Who would you like to add?</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach (EmployeeCurrentUserCanAssign employee in Model.EmployeesCurrentUserCanAssign)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBox("selectedItem", true, new {@value = @employee.EmployeeId})</td>
                            <td>@employee.FirstName</td>
                            <td>@employee.LastName</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnConfirmGroupAssign">
                    Assign Checked
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Controller get and post for this modal

```
        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult AddGroup(int projectNumber)
        {
            ProjectDetailsDTO project;
            ManageTeamModel viewModel;

            project = _projectService.GetProjectDetails(projectNumber);
            viewModel = MapProjectToManageTeamViewModel(project);
            return PartialView("_GroupAssignModal", viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GroupAssign(int projectNumber)
        {
            ProjectDetailsDTO project;
            ManageTeamModel viewModel;

            project = _projectService.GetProjectDetails(projectNumber);
            viewModel = MapProjectToManageTeamViewModel(project);

            var empList = viewModel.EmployeesCurrentUserCanAssign.Select(x => x.EmployeeId).ToList();
            var assignedList = _projectService.GetTeamMembersDetails(projectNumber).Select(x => x.EmployeeID).ToList();

            foreach (var employeeId in empList)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!assignedList.Contains(employeeId))
                    {
                        _projectService.AssignTeamMember(projectNumber, employeeId, false);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    continue;
                }
               
            }

            return PartialView("ManageTeam", viewModel);
        }
```

This is my Scripts for the modal

```
_ctx.on('click', '#GroupAssignModalJS', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            teamService.addGroup(_projectNumber, function (response) {
                var bsModal = $(response);
                _ctx.append(bsModal);
                bsModal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                    bsModal.remove();
                });

                bsModal.modal('show');
            });
        });
_ctx.on('click', '#btnConfirmGroupAssign', function () {
            teamService.groupAssign(_projectNumber, function (response) {
                _ctx.find('#groupAssignSettingModal').modal('hide');

                _ctx.update(response);
                location.reload();
            });
            
        });

addGroup: function () {
            $.get('./Team/AddGroup', { projectNumber: arguments[0]}, arguments[1]);
        },
groupAssign: function () {
            $.post('./Team/GroupAssign', { projectNumber: arguments[0] }, arguments[1]);
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, testing, and experimentation I was able to add a form and transfer the data in a Form Collection using jQuery. Not sure if this is the best way to accomplish what I was looking for, however, it is sufficient for my case.

My Model stayed the same.

My controllers post changed significantly to perform what I needed. The main part was adding Form Collection as a parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GroupAssign(int projectNumber, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            ProjectDetailsDTO project;
            ManageTeamModel viewModel;



            project = _projectService.GetProjectDetails(projectNumber);
            viewModel = MapProjectToManageTeamViewModel(project);


            List<string> employeeCollection = new List<string>();
            for(int i= 0; i< formCollection.AllKeys.Count(); ++i)
             {
                    {
                     employeeCollection.Add(formCollection.Get(i));
                    }
             }

            try
            {
                employeeCollection.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return ExceptionStatusCode(ex);
            }
            List<string> selectedEmpList = new List<string>();


            foreach(var emp in employeeCollection)
            {
                if (emp.StartsWith("9"))
                {
                    selectedEmpList.Add(emp);
                }
            }

            var empList = viewModel.EmployeesCurrentUserCanAssign.Select(x => x.EmployeeId).ToList();
            var assignedList = _projectService.GetTeamMembersDetails(projectNumber).Select(x => x.EmployeeID).ToList();

             foreach (var employeeId in empList)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!assignedList.Contains(employeeId) && selectedEmpList.Contains(employeeId))
                    {
                        _projectService.AssignTeamMember(projectNumber, employeeId, false);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    continue;
                }
               
            }

            return PartialView("ManageTeam", viewModel);
        }
```

My View changed very slightly. I added a Form tag open and close inside the modal and changed the button to a submit.

```
<div class="modal" id="groupAssignSettingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Who would you like to add?</h3>
            </div>
            <form id="frmConfirmGroupAssign">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Select</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            </tr>
                            @foreach (EmployeeCurrentUserCanAssign employee in Model.EmployeesCurrentUserCanAssign)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedemp" checked="checked" value="@employee.EmployeeId" /></td>
                                    <td>@employee.FirstName</td>
                                    <td>@employee.LastName</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Assign Checked
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My scripts for the Modal submit changed slightly as well.

```
_ctx.on('submit', '#frmConfirmGroupAssign', function (e) {
            var data = $(this).serializeArray();
            teamService.groupAssign(_projectNumber, data, function (response) {
                _ctx.find('#groupAssignSettingModal').modal('hide');

                _ctx.update(response);
                
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            location.reload();
        });

},


groupAssign: function () {
            $.post('./Team/GroupAssign', { projectNumber: arguments[0], employeeId: arguments[1]}, arguments[2]);
        },
```

The big takeaways I learned was how I can use form collections to pass data (in this instance my checkbox values) back into my controller through jQuery. I hope this helps someone else who may end up stuck with a similar issue.